# How to make a datetime object of the date in a filename?

Tags: python, datetime, regex-group

Im trying to extract the datetime inside a filename and make a datetime format of it like this: `2021-10-24 19:37:11`

**This is my code:**

```
import re
import datetime

my_string = 'Afo_20211024-19u37m11s_ab.txt'
date_time= re.search("_(.\d+)_ab.txt", file_name).group(1)
"create a datetime here..."
```

**This is my output:**

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**

Comment: The date/time part `20211024-19u37m11s` doesn't contain only digits; you'll have to make the regex more specific

Comment: What should I add?

Comment: if you're not sure how the filename string looks like besides the date/time part, a specific regex would be `'[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{2}u[0-9]{2}m[0-9]{2}s'`. just do a re.search and parse the match if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. You can find the codes to use with datetime.strptime here: [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

The second argument to `strptime` is the pattern we are matching against. Each of the %X represent part of the datetime, but we also can have filler like '-' and 'u', 'm', 's' as part of the pattern.

```
import datetime
time_string = 'Afo_20211024-19u37m11s_ab.txt'.split('_')[1]
date = datetime.strptime(time_string,'%Y%m%d-%Hu%Mm%Ss')
```

If the files always start and end with the same stuff, and only the datetime part varies, then you could even get rid of line 2 and just have all of that start and end filler inside the datetime pattern.

Comment: Works great! To make it more robust I made this of it:
`datetime=  datetime.datetime.strptime(file_name.split('_')[1],'%Y%m%d-%Hu%Mm%Ss')`